# Scoring first word with all 7 letters

Tags: scrabble, scoring

What scoring conditions apply if all 7 letters are used for the first word in Scrabble? Does the player get double points for the word AND 50 points for using all their tiles?

Answer (score 9):

You get both.

In fact, there are three bonuses that you can get on your first turn, evaluated in this order:

- Double letter score (if you play your word such that it hits one of the double letter scores that are 5 away from the starting square)
- Double word score (from the starting square)
- Bingo: +50 points for using all your letters

Let's say you play the word "LETTERS", with the L on a double letter score.  You would get 66 points:

1. Base 7 for tiles: all these tiles are 1 point
2. 8 points post double letter score (the L is doubled to 2 points)
3. 16 points post double word score
4. 66 points post bonus